# How to enable search bar in unity console

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have console unity like that 
[image]

how can I turn on or enable the search bar as in below image
[image]

I wanna have something like B frame in the image above

Answer (score 1):

It's a plugin: http://unityconsole.com/

You can enable it in that add-on's options.